# is this acceptable for the 4 color theorem?

Tags: coloring

I've seen some videos and done some general reading on the 4 color theorem and it's mostly been presented in simple circular like maps or networks, i took a shot at trying to make a map that could be taken as a counter example but i can't seem to simplify it to match the circular maps or even a network that doesn't look like a tangled mess, regardless i'd like to know if it would be considered(I also saw that there were some mentions of networks not allowing more than 5 connections to a singular junction, perhaps i missunderstood since i made a pattern 3 junctions with around 10 connections, all interconnected with eachother), perhaps it might be my lack of capability, thank you in advance, the patterns and the network is as follows, respectively:

[image]

(EDIT!!!!:this picture has a mistake in it, the design it should follow is the following):

[image]

(EDIT2:the previous picture  but attempted with color):
[image]

[image]

(Note: the reason why the network was drawn with green dots and black lines is purely because of the colors chosen randomly at the time, given that i couldn't solve or have the program i used solve it)

The reason why i ask whether this would become acceptable as a counter proof is because i ran a few tests on a website, and the program tried and ended up repeating colors, on this and another pattern i drew, was curious whether i'd have to reformulate.

Once again a great thank you for your help in advance, i'll also take any explanation as to what makes a map acceptable or not :D!

EDIT:Corrected a picture
EDIT2: added the corrected picture with an attempt to fill with color with the following website:https://www.kleemans.ch/four-color-theorem-map-solver

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit your question so that it is self-contained. I am not clicking on link from a new user and I recommend no one else do so either.

Comment: @Mike That's difficult for a question like this - new users aren't allowed to input images, and the OP's images are complicated enough that it would be very difficult for them to include them otherwise. I'll go ahead and edited to include the pictures.

Comment: However, to the OP: no, this isn't a counterexample. It's easily 4-colorable, and the site you've linked to **does** solve it (at least, on my browser). See [here](https://imgur.com/a/ZLLShQt).

Comment: Note that your proposal is unnecessarily complicated. In any graph $G$, if $G$ is non-four-colorable and $v$ is a vertex with at most three neighbors, then $G-v$ is still non-four-colorable (more transparently, a four-coloring of $G-v$ can be extended to a four-coloring of $G$). So a lot of the vertices in your graph aren't actually doing anything. In fact, this suggests a useful iterative strategy for finding four-colorings of a graph: start by repeatedly removing "small-connectivity" vertices until you can't do that any more, then four-color the resulting simpler graph.

Comment: The observation in my above comment also suggests a strategy for **proving** the four color theorem that looks quite promising ... for about five seconds. (The actual proof is a bit more complicated, to put it mildly. However, the basic idea of a kind of "recursive simplification" approach does stick around!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image: newer version]

This map is not a counterexample to the 4 color theorem

Comment: I made a mistake copying the design so it would be more suitable, sorry for the mistake, the original has an extra seperation at the bottom where the green is, i'm editing the post to make it clear

Comment: @David It's still not going to work. And per my last comment above, most of your proposed graph can be removed without actually affecting the result.

Comment: @NoahSchweber As much as i'd care to agree, the problem that stands is that by removing the "small-connectivity" vertices i'd be removing that connectivity from the higher connectivity ones, which allow for much higher flexibility of choice of colors, i've redone the original design and added it to the post, you can see it has 2 green junctions on the bottom and fails the test.

Comment: @David That doesn't matter, the proof still works. In fact, what you describe is a positive feature: it allows the same trick to be iterated usefully (we can at stage 2 remove some vertices we couldn't remove at stage 1).

Comment: Added coloring for the new (20:04:44Z) version.

Comment: @David All that demonstrates is that sometimes we need to **backtrack**; it doesn't show that the modified graph is not four-colorable. Indeed, the same website successfully four-colors it (see [here](https://imgur.com/a/vaVHWsO)). Maybe you're having a browser issue?

Comment: @NoahSchweber my apologies, it would seem as for some reason my browser refuses to work with this, if you or anyone has some way to verify any given map with consistency i'd be thankful

Comment: @David Just try a different browser.